# Request merge method null when called from phpunit?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm merging new field into the input data array via merge method.

In the request class:
`$this->merge(['mykey' => $myvalue]);`

So when I call my endpoint from Insomnia/Postman everything works perfect.

In the controller:
`$myVariable = $request->get('mykey')`

But when I tried to test endpoint via phpunit, after debbuging I found that $myVariable always null.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Could you please paste your code to see what's wrong/missing?

Comment: Problem was sold by using request magic method, so $request->mykey.

Comment: Glad you solve your it. But for future questions you need to add more information mate.

Comment: Ok, will be more wide next time, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by using request magic method, so `$request->mykey`. It seems like different request types in phpunit, but I'm not sure.